# Regex only matches once

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have the following regex that matches only once:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("POLYGON\\s\\(\\((([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+)\\s([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+),?)+\\)\\)")
                   .matcher("POLYGON ((12.789754538957263 36.12443963532555,12.778550292768816 36.089875458584984,12.77760353347314 36.12427601168043))");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("-> " + m.group(2) + " - " + m.group(3));
}
```

But it only prints the first match:

> -> 12.789754538957263 - 36.12443963532555

Why does it not match the other coordinates?

I want to print a new line for each pair of coordinates, e.g.

```
12.789754538957263 - 36.12443963532555
12.778550292768816 - 36.089875458584984
12.77760353347314 - 36.12427601168043
```

Comment: because you have only match which start with `POLYGON` no? can you tell us what you want to match exactly?

Comment: I want to print a new line for each pair of coordinates, e.g.
12.789754538957263 - 36.12443963532555\n
12.778550292768816 - 36.089875458584984\n
12.77760353347314 36.12427601168043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should look like this [`(\[0-9\]*\.\[0-9\]+)\s(\[0-9\]*\.\[0-9\]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/MUn7uu/1)

```
String input = ...
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+)\\s([0-9]*\\.[0-9]+)").matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("-> " + m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2));
}
```

Outputs

```
-> 12.789754538957263 - 36.12443963532555
-> 12.778550292768816 - 36.089875458584984
-> 12.77760353347314 - 36.12427601168043
```

If you want to make sure that the input should between `POLYGON (( .. ))` you can use `replaceAll` to extract that inputs :

```
12.789754538957263 36.12443963532555,12.778550292768816 36.089875458584984,12.77760353347314 36.12427601168043
```

Your code should be :

```
.matcher(input.replaceAll("POLYGON \\(\\((.*?)\\)\\)", "$1"));
```

Instead of :

```
.matcher(input);
```

### Solution 2

After analysing your problem, I think you need just this :

```
Stream.of(input.replaceAll("POLYGON \\(\\((.*?)\\)\\)", "$1").split(","))
             .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: So I can't make sure the input string starts with "POLYGON ((" and create the desired output at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You could still check if your input begins with a certain string like the following.

I'd use the following regex to do the check : [**`(\[\\d.\]+)\\s(\[\\d.\]+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/vRG5Ui/1)

It searches for sequences of digits or points separated by a space.

```
String input = ...
if (input.startsWith("POLYGON")) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([\\d.]+)\\s([\\d.]+)").matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("-> " + m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2));
    }
}
```